# convert wmf to jpg with graphicsmagick produces black image

Tags: graphicsmagick, wmf

I have a wmf file (extracted thumbnail from an Excel file) which I want to convert to a jpg using the following graphicsmagick command:

gm.exe convert 123.wmf 123.jpg

The result is a black square. (the same happens if I try to open the file with Gimp). I can open the wmf file in Windows paint (plus another viewer) and it shows ok.

Here's the wmf file: https://mycloud.m-box.at/index.php/s/qNW2RvwRNNfkc3J

I am using the latest version of gm (1.3.29)

Comment: You should never use JPG for non-photographic images, especially not those suitable for vector representation!

Answer (score 1):

First check if you have installed support for the `WMF` format:

```
gm identify -version
GraphicsMagick 1.3.28 2018-01-20 Q16 http://www.GraphicsMagick.org/
Copyright (C) 2002-2018 GraphicsMagick Group.
Additional copyrights and licenses apply to this software.
See http://www.GraphicsMagick.org/www/Copyright.html for details.

Feature Support:
  Native Thread Safe       yes
  Large Files (> 32 bit)   yes
  Large Memory (> 32 bit)  yes
  BZIP                     yes
  DPS                      no
  FlashPix                 no
  FreeType                 yes
  Ghostscript (Library)    no
  JBIG                     no
  JPEG-2000                yes
  JPEG                     yes
  Little CMS               no
  Loadable Modules         yes
  OpenMP                   no
  PNG                      yes
  TIFF                     yes
  TRIO                     no
  UMEM                     no
  WebP                     no
  WMF                      yes    <--- HERE IT IS
  X11                      no
  XML                      yes
  ZLIB                     yes

Host type: x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0

Configured using the command:
  ./configure  '--prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/graphicsmagick/1.3.28_1' '--disable-dependency-tracking' '--enable-shared' '--disable-static' '--with-modules' '--without-lzma' '--disable-openmp' '--with-quantum-depth=16' '--without-gslib' '--with-gs-font-dir=/usr/local/share/ghostscript/fonts' '--with-webp=no' '--without-x' '--without-lcms2' 'CC=clang' 'CXX=clang++'

Final Build Parameters:
  CC       = clang
  CFLAGS   = -g -O2 -Wall -D_THREAD_SAFE
  CPPFLAGS = -I/usr/local/opt/freetype/include/freetype2 -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/libxml2
  CXX      = clang++
  CXXFLAGS = -D_THREAD_SAFE
  LDFLAGS  = -L/usr/local/opt/freetype/lib -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib
  LIBS     = -lfreetype -lbz2 -lz -lltdl -lm -lpthread
```

Then, if you do not see `WMF=yes`, you will need to reconfigure and rebuild **GraphicsMagick**. So, look for the line that shows you how the current build is configured, in my example it is:

```
Configured using the command:

  ./configure  '--prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/graphicsmagick/1.3.28_1' '--disable-dependency-tracking' '--enable-shared' '--disable-static' '--with-modules' '--without-lzma' '--disable-openmp' '--with-quantum-depth=16' '--without-gslib' ...
```

and remove the

```
'--without-wmf'
```

and re-instll the usual way:

```
./configure ...
make -j4
sudo make install
```

Then you can do:

```
gm convert -density 288 123.wmf result.jpg
```

[image]

---

If you are on `macOS`, it is just:

```
brew reinstall graphicsmagick --with-libwmf
```

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate answer! WMF support was and is included. I installed the latest version 1.3.29, problem still persists, though. I am using the precompiled Windows-version of gm. Some wmf files (thumbnails from MS Word) are converted properly.